# What is happening to my cloth simulation? It explodes for some reason

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I am trying to make a walk cycle, and the mesh I am using has a side skirt. I wanted to make that skirt react to the leg movement,so when my mesh moves her leg, the skirt reacts to it. Yet for some reason it explodes and goes crazy.

[image]

The legs have have the collision physics, with it the cloth explodes, but without it, the cloth doesn´t work. Any tips?

Here is my file

[image]

Comment: A couple of points:  1) you should not have an Armature modifier on the Cloth, and 2) you Cloth starts out on the inside of the left leg, a collision object

Comment: Also problems with cloth underneath the right leg, and not all vertices of the dress along the top are in the Pin group.

Comment: Thank you @james_t it helped quite a bit, its much better now, though the skirt still is going crazy, its more usable now!

Comment: please update your blend file accordingly...and please do file -> external data -> pack resources + save  before uploading

Comment: There are unfortunately 10 million fine tuning knobs on Physics Modifiers, of which one can usually master 3;  I wish there was a "do not explode" checkbox for cloth and SoftBody, LOL.